# SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: null (HikariDataSource)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I created an application to run a schedule function using Spring and Maven, it is working well, but it keep throwing an exception when I run the spring application:

`java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: null`

**log**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.1)

2022-10-12 19:11:03.422  INFO 15444 --- [           main] y.YoutubeDataCollectorApplication        : Starting YoutubeDataCollectorApplication using Java 11.0.14 on DESKTOP-LJ758EN with PID 15444 (C:\projects\youtubedatacollector\target\classes started by moham in C:\projects\youtubedatacollector)
2022-10-12 19:11:03.429  INFO 15444 --- [           main] y.YoutubeDataCollectorApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-10-12 19:11:03.430 DEBUG 15444 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class youtubedatacollector.YoutubeDataCollectorApplication
2022-10-12 19:11:03.493 DEBUG 15444 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@4233e892
2022-10-12 19:11:04.066  INFO 15444 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-10-12 19:11:04.081  INFO 15444 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 6 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-10-12 19:11:04.540 DEBUG 15444 --- [           main] .s.b.w.e.t.TomcatServletWebServerFactory : Code archive: C:\Users\moham\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.7.1\spring-boot-2.7.1.jar
2022-10-12 19:11:04.541 DEBUG 15444 --- [           main] .s.b.w.e.t.TomcatServletWebServerFactory : Code archive: C:\Users\moham\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.7.1\spring-boot-2.7.1.jar
2022-10-12 19:11:04.541 DEBUG 15444 --- [           main] .s.b.w.e.t.TomcatServletWebServerFactory : None of the document roots [src/main/webapp, public, static] point to a directory and will be ignored.
2022-10-12 19:11:04.561  INFO 15444 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-10-12 19:11:04.571  INFO 15444 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-10-12 19:11:04.571  INFO 15444 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.64]
2022-10-12 19:11:04.686  INFO 15444 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-10-12 19:11:04.686 DEBUG 15444 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
2022-10-12 19:11:04.686  INFO 15444 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1193 ms
2022-10-12 19:11:04.703 DEBUG 15444 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Mapping filters: characterEncodingFilter urls=[/*] order=-2147483648, formContentFilter urls=[/*] order=-9900, requestContextFilter urls=[/*] order=-105
2022-10-12 19:11:04.703 DEBUG 15444 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Mapping servlets: dispatcherServlet urls=[/]
2022-10-12 19:11:04.720 DEBUG 15444 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Filter 'requestContextFilter' configured for use
2022-10-12 19:11:04.720 DEBUG 15444 --- [           main] s.b.w.s.f.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter : Filter 'characterEncodingFilter' configured for use
2022-10-12 19:11:04.720 DEBUG 15444 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedFormContentFilter     : Filter 'formContentFilter' configured for use
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
DEBUG StatusLogger org.slf4j.helpers.Log4jLoggerFactory is not on classpath. Good!
2022-10-12 19:11:04.824  INFO 15444 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-10-12 19:11:04.828  WARN 15444 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2022-10-12 19:11:04.980  INFO 15444 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-10-12 19:11:05.021  INFO 15444 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-10-12 19:11:05.066  INFO 15444 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.9.Final
2022-10-12 19:11:05.068  INFO 15444 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect, hibernate.connection.password=****, hibernate.connection.username=root, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CLASP_DB?useSSL=false, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false}
2022-10-12 19:11:05.239  INFO 15444 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-10-12 19:11:05.336  WARN 15444 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: null
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:135) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at youtubedatacollector.YoutubeDataCollectorApplication.main(YoutubeDataCollectorApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]

2022-10-12 19:11:05.344  INFO 15444 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2022-10-12 19:11:05.487  INFO 15444 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-10-12 19:11:05.500  INFO 15444 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-10-12 19:11:05.682 DEBUG 15444 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ModelAttribute, 0 @InitBinder, 1 RequestBodyAdvice, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2022-10-12 19:11:05.753 DEBUG 15444 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 2 mappings in 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
2022-10-12 19:11:05.777 DEBUG 15444 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Patterns [/webjars/**, /**] in 'resourceHandlerMapping'
2022-10-12 19:11:05.788 DEBUG 15444 --- [           main] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
2022-10-12 19:11:05.824 DEBUG 15444 --- [           main] inMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin : Application Admin MBean registered with name 'org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication'
2022-10-12 19:11:05.920  INFO 15444 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-10-12 19:11:05.929  INFO 15444 --- [   scheduling-1] y.scheduled.ApiCaller                    : The time is now 19:11:05
2022-10-12 19:11:05.930 DEBUG 15444 --- [           main] ySourcesPropertyResolver$DefaultResolver : Found key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in PropertySource 'systemProperties' with value of type String
2022-10-12 19:11:05.933  INFO 15444 --- [           main] y.YoutubeDataCollectorApplication        : Started YoutubeDataCollectorApplication in 3.007 seconds (JVM running for 4.055)
2022-10-12 19:11:05.934 DEBUG 15444 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state LivenessState changed to CORRECT
2022-10-12 19:11:05.936 DEBUG 15444 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state ReadinessState changed to ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC
2022-10-12 19:11:10.939  INFO 15444 --- [   scheduling-1] y.scheduled.ApiCaller                    : The time is now 19:11:10
2022-10-12 19:11:15.932  INFO 15444 --- [   scheduling-1] y.scheduled.ApiCaller                    : The time is now 19:11:15
2022-10-12 19:11:20.944  INFO 15444 --- [   scheduling-1] y.scheduled.ApiCaller                    : The time is now 19:11:20
```

I thought its a configuration problem, so I checked my Database connection and wrote them in the application.properties as well as in the Hibernate.properties

possible problem, while I am using the same code to generate database entities, I am using some generate templets, could that effect the Spring functionality?

here is my configurations:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<groupId>clasp</groupId>
<artifactId>youtubeDataCollector</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>youtube-data-collector</name>
<description>YouTube API Data Collector</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.30</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        <!--generate sources (mvn hibernate-tools:hbm2java ) -->
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.20.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/hibernate.properties</propertyFile>
                <revengFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/hibernate.reveng.xml</revengFile>
                <ejb3>true</ejb3>
                <jdk5>true</jdk5>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                <packageName>generatedEntities</packageName>
                <templatePath>${project.basedir}/src/ApplicationStarter.ProjectStarter/resources/templates</templatePath>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- DB Driver of your database -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>8.0.12</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CLASP_DB?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure=ERROR
```

**Hibernate.properties**

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CLASP_DB?useSSL=false
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=password
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure=ERROR
```

**Spring Application main Class**:

```
package youtubedatacollector;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class YoutubeDataCollectorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(YoutubeDataCollectorApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and last but not least the **Scheduled Class** :

```
package youtubedatacollector.scheduled;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

@Component
public class ApiCaller {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiCaller.class);

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void collectorSchedule() {
        log.info("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

I know It could be over thinking for some of you :D
but I would like either to have a clean Log, or at least understand the Error in order to Ignore it or deep searching to fix it

Comment: i think no need of hibernate.properties.

Comment: Thank you, it worked !
however I need the Hibernate.properties, since I am generating the DB Entities my hibernate, but your answer still really helpful to point out the problem

Comment: welcome bro, can i know how it worked in last?

Comment: I deleted the hibernate.properties and the error is gone, I expect its one of Spring libraries (HikariCP-4.0.3) is confused between application.properties and Hibernate.properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got it right, all thanks to "[andeep Kumar Nat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74045918/6826975)" commit witch drive me right to the problem (hibernate.properties), and here is the result for future readers:

The "springframework" (version 2.7.*) they are using a library called [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) witch using the hibernate.properties file, and it sound that my properties file override their, but it should not be a serious problem if you are not using their library specifically, and operantly from their code, they are using the hibernate.properties file only in test (hard-coded).

**solution**
I simply rename the "hibernate.properties" to "generateEntities.hibernate.properties" and reconfigure it in the pom.xml file, and the error is gone :)

**the pom part where I am using the properties file**

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.20.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/generateEntities.hibernate.properties</propertyFile>
                <revengFile>src/main/resources/generateEntities.hibernate.reveng.xml</revengFile>
                <ejb3>true</ejb3>
                <jdk5>true</jdk5>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                <packageName>generatedEntities</packageName>
                <templatePath>${project.basedir}/src/ApplicationStarter.ProjectStarter/resources/templates</templatePath>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- DB Driver of your database -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>8.0.12</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

I hope it solve the problem for others, and thanks again to "[andeep Kumar Nat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74045918/6826975)" to point the problem

Answer (score 2):

Make this change:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

and Delete

```
hibernate.properties
```

Comment: unfortunately, still the same error

Comment: comment  all in hibernate.properties and delete mysql version in dependency

Comment: how it solved now

Answer (score 1):

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

has been deprecated so try this in  application properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: unfortunately, still the same error.
however thanks for the advice (deprecated) I changed it anyway ;)