"org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction" bei Maven-Multi-Module-App
My boss gave me a Spring Boot application that ran on Spring 2.7 and Kafka. I was supposed to migrate it to Spring 3 (works). Then the task was to install hibernate and liquibase. The way that a change in the DB schema (Postgres) causes a change in the Java entities also works. But that a change in the entities causes a change in the corresponding table throws the following exception:
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:466) ~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:531) ~[spring-tx-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:405) ~[spring-tx-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:617) ~[spring-tx-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:386) ~[spring-tx-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220) ~[spring-aop-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy208.findAllNotClearedYet(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.allianz.paymentmanagementservice.adapters.postgres.businessAccountClearingSchedule.BusinessAccountClearingScheduleFindAdapter.findAllNotClearedYet(BusinessAccountClearingScheduleFindAdapter.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.allianz.paymentmanagementservice.service.businessAccountClearingSchedule.BusinessAccountClearingScheduleFindServiceImpl.findAllNotClearedYet(BusinessAccountClearingScheduleFindServiceImpl.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.allianz.paymentmanagementservice.schedulers.ClearingScheduledTask.executeScheduledClearing(ClearingScheduledTask.java:74) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.runInternal(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:130) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.lambda$run$2(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:124) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:499) ~[micrometer-observation-1.12.4.jar:1.12.4]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:124) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection [null] [n/a]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:232) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:176) ~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:420) ~[spring-orm-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: null
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:135) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    ... 39 common frames omitted

application.yaml
spring:
  mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: ANT_PATH_MATCHER
  datasource:
    url: ${DB_URL:jdbc:postgresql://payment-management-postgres:5432/payment-management}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD:xxx}
    username: ${DB_USER_NAME:xxxxx}
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    hikari:
      connectionTimeout: '20000'
      maximumPoolSize: '5'
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  sql:
    init:
      mode: never
  profiles:
    active: ${SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE:local}

# Only one clearing strategy can be active at a time, please make sure only one line is uncommented
clearing:
  agcs: true
#  abs: true


kafka:
  bootstrap:
    #servers: 127.0.0.1:9092 #local without docker
    servers: localhost:8670 #local with docker

incoming:
  payment:
    new:
      path: file:./application/src/main/resources/incoming-payment/new
    archive:
      path: file:./application/src/main/resources/incoming-payment/archive
    schedule:
      duration: 600000

#
# Public ID sequence numbers have to be configured for each entity type as specified below
# The prefix cannot be empty, minimum 1 letter, maximum 9 letters
# The delimiter can be empty or a single character (non-letter, non-number)
# Number length:
# - If include-incrementing-letters = true: minimum 9, maximum 18
# - If include-incrementing-letters = false: minimum 12, maximum 18
# Starting number must be between 0 and 9
# Include incrementing letters means after 9 is reached, letter "A" will be used. Only capital letters are added, from A to Z
# Example: PRM_000000000001 -> PRM_00000000000A
#
# Example values:
# PRM_000000000001
# PRM_000000000002
# PRM_000000000003
# ...
# PRM_000000000009
# PRM_00000000000A
# PRM_00000000000B
# PRM_00000000000C
#...
# PRM_00000000000Z
# PRM_000000000010
# ...
# PRM_00000000001Z
# PRM_000000000020
#

sequence-configuration:
  list:
  - id: BOOKING.PREMIUM
    entity: BOOKING
    type: INVOICE
    sequence-prefix: PRM
    delimiter:
    number-length: 12
    starting-number: 1
    include-incrementing-letters: true
 ...

application-local.yml:
spring:
  mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: ANT_PATH_MATCHER
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/payment_management_postgredb
    password: my_password
    username: my_user
    #password: mysecretpassword
    #username: postgres
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
# Note: Comment line above and uncomment below to create the DB:
#      ddl-auto: create
#      properties:
#            javax:
#              persistence:
#                schema-generation:
#                  scripts:
#                    action: create
#                    create-target: create.sql
  sql:
    init:
      mode: never
      # Note: Comment line above and uncomment below to create the DB:
      #mode: always
  liquibase:
    enabled: false
    url: payment_management_postgredb@localhost

#  jpa:
#    properties:
#      javax:
#        persistence:
#          schema-generation:
#            scripts:
#              action: create
#              create-target: create.sql

# Only one clearing strategy can be active at a time, please make sure only one line is uncommented
clearing:
  agcs: true
#  abs: true

kafka:
  bootstrap:
    #servers: 127.0.0.1:9092 #local without docker
    servers: localhost:8670 #local with docker


pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.allianz.services</groupId>
        <artifactId>payment-management-service-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>payment-management-service-infrastructure</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>infrastructure</name>
    <description>Infrastructure</description>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Please see the parent POM file for common dependencies -->

        <!-- Module-specific dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.allianz.services</groupId>
            <artifactId>payment-management-service-domain</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok-mapstruct-binding.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-tools/blob/main/maven/docs/5-minute-tutorial.md -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.tool</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-tools-maven</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate-tools-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/hibernate.properties</propertyFile>
                    <revengFile>src/main/resources/hibernate.reveng.xml</revengFile>
                    <ejb3>true</ejb3>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <packageName>generatedEntities</packageName>
                    <templatePath>${project.basedir}/src/ApplicationStarter.ProjectStarter/resources/templates</templatePath>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.postgresql.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate.tool</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-tools-orm</artifactId>
                        <version>${hibernate-tools-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>entity-generation</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>hbm2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <ejb3>true</ejb3>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://:5432/payment_management_postgredb</url>
                    <outputChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml</outputChangeLogFile>
                    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-changelog.yaml</changeLogFile>
                    <diffTypes>tables,views,columns,indexes,foreignkeys,primarykeys,uniqueconstraints,data</diffTypes>

                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <!--                <driver>liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver</driver>-->
                    <username>xxx</username>
                    <password>xxx</password>
                    <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:com.allianz.paymentmanagementservice</referenceUrl>
                    <defaultSchemaName>public</defaultSchemaName>
                    <!--                <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:com.baeldung.liquibase.model?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</referenceUrl>-->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.postgresql.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate6</artifactId>
                        <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>${jpa.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${validation-api.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                        <version>${javassist.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>



        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


I've already tried a few things (including Error using com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource) but to no avail. What have I overlooked?

You have to rename hibernate.properties file. Hopefully this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74045768/sqlfeaturenotsupportedexception-null-hikaridatasource

tried it already. It did not work. I get the same messages

the exception says SQLFeatureNotSupportedException have you tried to open SQL logs with hibernate or p6spy ?

there are no generated sql-logs
